# How to get the name of all .resx files and load into a ComboBox in C#

Tags: c#, combobox, directory, runtime

is it possible to get the names of .resx files? In runtime. I need to capture those names to get the available languages and load them into a combobox. 
I have a folder

```
ProjectName
    Multilanguage
       Language.resx
       Language.en-US.resx
       Language.fr-FR.resx
```

I need in an array the names **Language.resx, Language.en-US.resx and Language.fr-FR.resx**

Thx!

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you asking how to create an array of filenames from a folder at runtime? If so, the question has been asked (and answered) here many times. If you're asking something different, [edit] your post and make it clear what you're wanting to do.

Comment: https://www.dotnetperls.com/directory-getfiles

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks and sorry. Yes, at runtime. I need to capture those names to get the available languages and load them into a combobox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [GetFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316(v=vs.110).aspx) method on the [Directory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory(v=vs.110).aspx) class to get all files recursively. It even supports a pattern:

```
string[] result = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\source\project", 
                  "*.resx", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Comment: Note: while OP found this helpful (and indeed it is a correct solution for developer's machine), this code has nothing to do with actually enumerating available resources (as satellite assemblies or embedded resources) in installed application when source code is not available.